# GeoWebCache without GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, mobile, geowebcache

I have a GeoServer (gs) and an stand-alone GeoWebCache (gwc). I seeded the gwc from the gs and pointed my clients to the gwc - everything works fine.

What I want to do now, is to remove the GeoServer and just take the gwc with me.

If running a gwc without a gs is not possible, what would be the easiest possibility to "clone" one or two layers from an existing gs and run it without the source gs ?

What I want to do, is to clone two layers from a company internal gs and carry these two layers around with me (use them in a demo system that has no connection to the source gs).

Our client requests the map data via WMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I think that what I wanted is not possible. GWC is really just for speeding up the distribution of map data but it is not usable (not intended to) as a mean to achieve high-availability because it can't server map data if the geoserver in the backend died.

I set up a second geoserver, create a WMS datasource and seedet the internal gwc from this data source. I think that it would also be possible to just copy the main geoserver but then it would be hard to keep both in sync.

Answer (score 5):

When using the standard XML configuration for layers, GWC only checks the back end if there's no tile in the cache, or if the cached tile is expired.  If you don't specify expiration, and fully seed the gridset you are covering, you no longer need the back end any more and if you copy the cache directory (including `geowebcache.xml`) elsewhere, it should serve the copied cache quite happily and I'm aware of several instances of people doing this, usually for security purposes.

The back end also need not be GeoServer, any WMS will do, and it can also read the a cache produced by ArcGIS Server off of the file system if it uses separate files (Reading AGS caches stored in one big file will be supported in GWC 1.6)

If you are using the WMS Capabilities layer configuration feature, that does require the ability to talk to the back end even if fully seeded, as does access to the local layers of GeoServer when using an embeded GWC instance.  There are hacks to get around this.